# What does $ sign mean in html template?

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, web.py

I am using web.py framework by using this helping tutorial.

[python and ajax](http://kooneiform.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/python-and-ajax-for-beginners-with-webpy-and-jquery/#comment-2352)

But I don't understand what does these $ sign means in tutorial.html

These variables with $ sign are shown as it is when I try to browse tutorial.html i.e.

via localhost

$def with (form, text)
$:form.render()
$text

Here is html from tutorial.html

```
$def with (form, text)

<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Python and AJAX tutorial for beginners with webpy and jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/tutorial.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                            jQuery(".button").click(function() {
                                    var input_string = $$("input#textfield").val();
                                    jQuery.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            data: {textfield : input_string},
                                            success: function(data) {
                                            jQuery('#foo').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1500);
                                            },
                                            });
                                    return false;
                                    });
                            });

                    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <form class="form" method="post"> 
    $:form.render()
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="send"/>    
    </form>

    <br><br>
    <span id="foo">$text</span>        
</body>    
</html>
```

When I’ve pressed “send” button then following Error message has been shown up:

“Error response

Error code 501.

Message: Can only POST to CGI scripts.

Error code explanation: 501 = Server does not support this operation.”

is there anyone who is using web.py ? Or anyone who understand this problem ?

Comment: Sounds like your click event isn't being bound, that or you aren't setting the correct target url in your ajax request (currently there is no target url)

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial itself explains it:

> The web.py templating language uses ‘$’ symbols to denote Python expressions (and the arguments passed into the template). To use an actual ‘$’ just escape it with ‘$$’. Note that it’s a popular habit in jQuery to also use the dollar sign to mean the jQuery object, but we can get around that conflict simply by using ‘jQuery’ instead in the JavaScript. There are other ways around that but I like this method for its simplicity and how it feels the same as Python namespaces.

Comment: Thanks Ter0:
I've red this and tried to add $$ sign as well i.e. "$$def with (form, text)" but still these $ signes are shown as it is on tutorial.html.

Comment: I am new to Python, I am trying to access .html page like we do in PHP i.e. localhost/tutorial.html, but i am not sure if it is right way or not. 

If i try to access app.py (mentioned in this tutorial) then all the source code of app.py shown on browser :@

I don't know what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

These are generally used to denote the expressions. In Most of the language such as Python, JSP etc. and the frameworks such as JQuery etc., they are used.

I don't know much about the python, but say I want to show the value from a request/session scope, so i just can use

value = ${myval}

similary in javascript, to denote the jquery, $ can be used... so jQuery("#some-element") also can be written as $("#some-element").